# Why vscode adds many files when I launch the Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I am new to vscode (have used Webstorm up til now).  I have the world's simplest project.  2 files:  index.html and index.js.  Index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js has only one line:

```
alert("Hello world");
```

The launch.json is this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "file": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html",
            "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works and the alert pops up.  BUT, vscode then writes a large number of empty dirs and various files into the folder.  Why?  How do I prevent it?  These are the files it writes.

```
App Shim Socket
BrowserMetrics-spare.pma
CertificateRevocation
CertificateTransparency
Default
FileTypePolicies
InterventionPolicyDatabase
Local State
MEIPreload
OriginTrials
PepperFlash
RunningChromeVersion
SSLErrorAssistant
Safe Browsing
Safe Browsing Channel IDs
Safe Browsing Channel IDs-journal
Safe Browsing Cookies
Safe Browsing Cookies-journal
ShaderCache
SingletonCookie
SingletonLock
SingletonSocket
Subresource Filter
WidevineCdm
pnacl
```

Comment: This is chrome, not VSCode, since you set its userdatadir to your workspace.

Comment: Ah so.  Thanks for the feedback.  That works.